# How to read a data from a device through PL2303 USB UART in android application?

Tags: android, embedded, system

I have tried using USB Host and reading data from a usb device. it's not working.
I'm using UsbRequest class for receiving data from the usb uart to my android host.
During trial n error I found that the connection is getting initiated but when I try to read data the app just set the text which I do in checkinfo() method.
Refer the below code and enlighten me where I'm going wrong.

```
package com.mobilemerit.usbhost;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;  
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;  
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.net.sip.SipAudioCall;
import android.net.sip.SipSession;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mobilemerit.usbhost.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
Button btnCheck;
TextView textInfo;
UsbDevice device;
UsbManager manager;
UsbInterface intf = null;
UsbEndpoint input = null;
UsbDeviceConnection connection;
UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
byte[] readBytes = new byte[64];
//GpsStatus.Listener listener;
//SipAudioCall.Listener listener;
SipSession.Listener listener;
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(64);
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =          "com.mobilemerit.usbhost.USB_PERMISSION";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
    textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            textInfo.setText("");
            checkInfo();
        }
    });

}

private void checkInfo() {
    manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    /*
     * this block required if you need to communicate to USB devices it's
     * take permission to device
     * if you want than you can set this to which device you want to communicate   
     */
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    String i = "";
    while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
        device = deviceIterator.next();
        manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
        i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
                + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
                + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
                + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n";
    }

    textInfo.setText(i);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        // call method to set up device communication
                        intf = device.getInterface(0);
                        input = intf.getEndpoint(2);
                        int dir = input.getDirection();
                        int number = input.getEndpointNumber();
                        int type = input.getType();
                        int max = input.getMaxPacketSize();
                        textInfo.setText("Direction:"+dir+
                                         "\nEndpoint number:"+number+
                                         "\nEndpoint Type:"+type+
                                         "\nMax Packet Size:"+max);
                        connection = manager.openDevice(device);
                        connection.claimInterface(intf,true);
                        boolean initialized = request.initialize(connection,input);
                        if (!initialized) {
                            textInfo.setText("Connection Failed to Initialized");
                        }
                        else {
                            textInfo.setText("Connection Initialized");
                        }

                        if (request.queue(buf, 64) == true) {
                             if (connection.requestWait() == request) {
                                    String result = new String(buf.array());
                                    Object obj = request.getClientData();
                                    result = obj.toString();
                                    textInfo.setText("Result is:"+result);

                                   //Log.i("DEVICE DATA : ", result);
                                   // listener.readData(result);
                             }
                             else{
                                    textInfo.setText("RequestWait failed!");
                             }
                        }
                        else{
                                textInfo.setText("Request can't be queued");
                        }



                    }
                    else{
                        textInfo.setText("device is null");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    textInfo.setText("Permission denied for the device");
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? What is happening then? Elaborate your question!

Comment: I have added my code Paresh. Please refer to that.
Thank you.

Comment: Here also listener.readData() method is giving some error. I don't know how to use it as I have copied that from a different website.
What class does it belong to?

Comment: The organization of your code doesn't make much sense - you apparently only access the device once, and only in the broadcast receiver where you first receive permission to it. Take a look at some decently architected examples for FTDI or CDC/ACM type devices and create one for your PL2303 by changing the specific USB bus operations.  Or even decide it's cheaper to buy one of those adapters for which there is already working code.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton for a suggestion!
Do you know about readData() mehod?
Which class does it belong?

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, I'm accessing just once the device and try to read data from the device. I'm using RFID technology in my micro controller. So when I swipe my card on it data should be read on the application.

Comment: As I said, your code doesn't make sense.  Right now it will be triggered by granting permission to the USB device.  You rather need something that keeps trying to read in a loop in a thread, so that it can be triggered by the act of swiping, which is not something that has any significant to Android, but merely generates data that can be read if **and only if** something is actively querying the USB peripheral.